# How to change the claim when the user is logged in

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

A user own many shops in my system.

After login, user can choose a certain shop which he wants to manage.

So, I add the claim named 'LoginShop' to UserClaims.

When a user chooses a shop to manage, I need to update the claim value to the selected shop id and then re-login.

I use the .net core identity and the serveridentity4 as the server, and the .net core mvc as the client.

So I have an action in the server to handle this.

```
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateShopClaim(int id)
    {
        if (id <= 0)
        {
            return Ok(new ServiceBaseResponse(0, "shop id not found", null));
        }

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
        var shop = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "LoginShop");
        if (shop == null)
        {
            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("LoginShop", id.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {

            await _userManager.ReplaceClaimAsync(user, shop, new Claim("LoginShop", id.ToString()));
        }

        return Ok(new ServiceBaseResponse(1, "ok", null));
    }
```

and the client code is

```
    public async Task<ServiceResponseBase> SelectShop(ApplicationUser user, int shopId)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent("{\"id\":" + shopId + "}");
            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var uri = API.Shop.SelectShop(_remoteIdentityUrl, shopId);
            HttpRequestMessage request=new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
            request.Content = httpContent;
            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var qa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResponseBase>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            return qa;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I always get the null value of the ControllerBase.User in the Server.

Is there anything wrong with me?

Comment: You should really not use claims to keep track of the current shop. You can add allowed shops as claims (a claim may be set more than once, turning it into a collection). If you want to keep track of the current shop use a cookie or route values, e.g. in MVC: /shop/1/products. Then you can check if user has a claim for shop 1. As for User is null, please note that this is something you'll need to configure with a cookie or token. Take a look at the IdentityServer4 samples for a simple configuration and start from there.

Answer (score 0):

Although you add the 'ContentType' HTTP header here:

```
httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

You didn't add the 'Cookie' request header along with any accompanying cookie obtained through the response of your initial authentication request. Without the cookie, IdentityServer does not know who the client is and will always have the base 'User' value used during the processing of the request.

You can learn more about the 'Cookie' header here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie